# Python mistaking float for string

Tags: python, string, floating-point, python-3.x

I receive

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

while using

```
Gambler.pot += round(self.bet + self.money * 0.1)
```

where pot, bet, and money are all doubles (or at least are supposed to be). I'm not sure if this is yet another Eclipse thing, but how do I get the line to compile?

Code where `bet` and `money` are initialized:

```
class Gambler:
    money = 0
    bet = 0
```

Test case:

```
number = 0
print("Here, the number is a {0}".format(type(number)))
number = input("Enter in something: ")
print("But now, it has turned into a {0}".format(type(number)))
```

Output from test case:

```
Here, the number is a <class 'int'>
Enter in something: 1
But now, it has turned into a <class 'str'>
```

Apparently, input() is changing it to a string.

**EDIT**: Finally fixed the problem (I think) with

```
self.bet = int(self.bet.strip())
```

after the user inputs the value. Though I dunno if that's the best way to fix the problem :)

A better solution by Daniel G.:

```
self.bet = float(input("How much would you like to bet? $"))
```

Comment: Please show the code where self.bet and self.money are initialized.

Comment: You haven't proven that those aren't strings.

Comment: Is that enough, or should I post more code?

Comment: Those are local variables. You need to show how they get bound as attributes of the object.

Comment: Like that? (extra chars)

Comment: Did you already try printing `type(self.bet)` and `type(self.money)` and `type(self.pot)` (right before the line that throws the exception) to see if they are indeed numbers?

Comment: @wallacoloo: thanks! pot is a float, bet is a string, and money is an int :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python3.2 <sup>(py3k:77602)</sup> gives these error messages:

```
>>> "1.2" * 0.1                                                #1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
>>> "3.4" + 1.2 * 0.1                                          #2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
>>> n = "42"
>>> n += round(3.4 + 1.2 * 0.1)                                #3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I suspect your error message is because one of your actual values is a string instead of the expected float in a scenario similar to #2, which is an exact match for your exception.

If you could write a [test](http://sscce.org) [case](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html), that would be a big help.

---

Remember that Py3.x's *input* is identical to Py2.x's ***raw**_input*, and Py2.x's *input* is gone (it's equivalent to using *evai*, which you don't want to do).  Because of this, *input* in 3.x will always return a string.  Use *int* to convert:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

If you want to handle input errors, then catch ValueError, which is what *int* raises on errors:

```
try:
  n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
except ValueError:
  print("invalid input")
else:
  print("squared:", n*n)
```

Comment: I'm using 3.1.1. I'll write the test case asap if I can :)

Comment: I did it... the problem seems to be that inputting something turns it into a string

Answer (score 6):

`input()` in 3.x only returns strings. It is the programmer's job to pass it to a numeric constructor in order to turn it into a number.

Comment: I believe `input()` in 3.x is the same as `raw_input()` in 2.x

Comment: @MatrixFogg: I get `NameError: global name 'raw_input' is not defined` when trying that out. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @wrongusername: 3.x doesn't have `raw_input()`, only `input()`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you initializing pot?  Have you tried storing intermediate results to track down here the problem is coming from?  And finally, do you know about [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)?  That may be a big help.

```
class Gambler:
    pot = 0.0
    def __init__(self, money=0.0)
        self.pot = 0.0
        self.bet = 0.0
        self.money = money

    def update_pot(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        to_pot = self.bet + self.money * 0.1
        to_pot = round(to_pot)
        Gambler.pot = Gambler.pot + to_pot
```

You will get a prompt when the set_trace() line is executed.  Try looking at the current values when you get there.

```
(Pdb) h    # help
(Pdb) n    # go to next statement
(Pdb) l    # list source code
...
(Pdb) to_pot
...
(Pdb) self.bet
...
(Pdb) self.money
...
(Pdb) Gambler.pot
...
(Pdb) c    # continue
```

Answer (score 3):

If any of `Gambler.pot`, `self.bet` or `self.money` have somehow become strings (because they were set to a string at some point), `+` will be taken to mean string concatenation which causes the error message you see.

Comment: It seems self.bet has after input :(

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.x, `input()` replaces Python 2.x's `raw_input()`. Therefore, the function `input()` returns the exact string that the user input (as `raw_input()` did in previous versions).

To get Python 2.x behavior, you can just do

```
number = eval(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

However, I wouldn't recommend using "eval" since the user can put any line of Python they want in there, which is probably not what you want. If you know you want a `float`, just tell Python that's what you want:

```
number = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

As was said in a comment, what you've shown is initializing local variables to 0.  Instead try something like:

```
class Gambler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bet = 0.0
        self.money = 0.0

    def calc_pot(self):
        self.pot = round(self.bet  + self.money * 0.1)

g = Gambler()
g.bet = 2.0
g.money = 5.0
g.calc_pot()

print "Pot = %f" % (g.pot)
```

Also, make sure there's nothing that might be turning those members into strings.